# Not able to use log4j2 in quarkus

Tags: log4j2, quarkus

I configured log4j2 as described at https://quarkus.io/guides/logging, but the logs that I printed with org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager never shows up.

I've tested using org.jboss.logging.Logger, it works. Although I can use jboss logger in this project instead of log4j2, some of the dependencies of my other base projects are using log4j2. Those logs are missing. So I hope to use log4j2 in quarkus, but not sure if it's possible.

pom dependencies

```
<properties>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.9.2.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.9.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j2-jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.rxnetworks.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxn-commons-utility</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.rxnetworks.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxn-commons-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
      <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.rxnetworks.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>rxn-commons-timeseries</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>28.2-jre</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Code example:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogTest
{
  private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();  // With log4j2 Logger, no logs show up
  // private static final org.jboss.logging.Logger LOG = org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(LogTest.class);           // If change to jboss Logger, it works
  public void test() {
      LOG.info("test log4j2");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the log level at which your application is?

If it is greater than INFO, the info logs will not log.

For reference, you can go through the below link.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/manual/customloglevels.html

Comment: Update the code to below.

`private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(LogTest.class.getName());`

Comment: The import used in the [https://quarkus.io/guides/logging] is `import org.jboss.logging.Logger;`. While auto importing chose the correct class.

Comment: Thank you for helping! It turned out I just made a stupid mistake, I didn't add 
**-Dlog4j.configurationFile=$path** while running the project.
Problem solved, Good to know that Quarkus does support log4j2. 
I'll close the issue.

Comment: how did you know you have to specify the log4j.configurationFile ? And where did you specify it?